# Separate read and write databases in Magento

Tags: magento

I can't find any examples online of how to configure two separate databases for Magento - one for read requests and one for write requests. I assume that this should happen in app/etc/local.xml but I don't know what the syntax is. Does anybody know the syntax or have a link to a blog post or something that my searching didn't turn up?

I'm running Magento 1.6.1.0

Thanks

Comment: Interesting question. May I ask you in what kind of scenario would separate DBs for read and write be use full?

Comment: For [Load Balancing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_%28computing%29). Magento is very read-intensive. By using [RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) read replica(s) I can distribute the load on the DB and handle more traffic.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In your `app/etc/local.xml` fill `<resources>` in next way:

```
    <resources>
        <db>
            <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
        </db>
        <core_read>
            <connection>
                <use /> 
                <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
                <password><![CDATA[]]></password>
                <dbname><![CDATA[db_read_name]]></dbname>
                <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                <active>1</active>
            </connection>
        </core_read>
        <core_write>
            <connection>
                <use />
                <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
                <password><![CDATA[]]></password>
                <dbname><![CDATA[db_write_name]]></dbname>
                <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                <active>1</active>
            </connection>
        </core_write>
    </resources>
```

Comment: I'm getting `Fatal error: Call to a member function getTableName() on a non-object in /path/to/magento/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php on line 296`
Any idea?

Comment: No ideas. Did you flush cache?

Comment: Just needed to add `<use></use>` so that it overwrote what was in app/etc/config.xml. However, i decided to overwrite default_read and default_write instead. I think its better.

Comment: Yeah, that `<use />` element is apparently critical.

Comment: I'm getting `Fatal error: Call to a member function setQueryHook() on a non-object in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php on line 347` in Magento CE 1.9.0.1 and I did include the `<use />`

Comment: @TylerV. and anyone else encountering that error, you'll need to override the config.xml defaults in your local.xml. My original local.xml has `default_setup` defined as the (now) write DB, so I just added a `default_read` block in which overrides the config.xml. Everything else stayed the same.

Comment: I have the same Fatal error than Tyler V. in magento 1.9.0.1 Any idea what's the problem?

Comment: I had to include default_setup or core_setup in order for this error to go away.

Comment: @TylersSN, can you please share your final setting in local.xml as need to setup the same.
Also are you facing any issue after this ?