# Magento database IP is cached

Tags: xml, magento, caching

We have different database IP addresses for our development and production environments. Our development environment is running locally on our developer machines and pointed to a single development database server on our local network. Our production environment uses a database hosted at RackSpace and is hosted on their local network. Somehow, it appears that our development IP address has been cached on production. Here's what I have done so far:

- Verified that the IP address in app/etc/local.xml on production is correct.
- Deleted the contents of var/cache/* and var/full_page_cache/*
- Restarted our memcached servers to clear any strange caches there
- grepped our entire codebase for the dev IP address
- Dumped the mysql database and grepped the dump for the dev IP (we were desperate)
- Deleted the contents of /tmp
- Disabled custom modules

This has been working for weeks without a problem. It was when I disabled the config cache that problem started. I know what you're thinking, that it just now finally picked up a config change that someone made since the last time the cache was cleared. That makes sense. What doesn't make sense is that I've cleared every cache mentioned above, [enabled the config cache using MageTool](https://github.com/alistairstead/MageTool) and everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it turns out, fixing this whole thing was a two step process.

Because our production and development environments require different IPs `app/etc/local.xml` is untracked and instead we track `app/etc/local-example.xml` so that all of our developers can quickly and easily copy it over to `app/etc/local.xml` and be up and running. This has become a bit of a company standard and we use it across all of our other projects. Thankfully, one of my coworkers discovered that [Magento loads all the xml files in `app/etc/`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515237/magento-cache-not-get-clear#comment15235264_11516317)

So, no, our development IP wasn't magically cached in some crazy obscure location, we were just inadvertently loading it. After renaming that file to `app/etc/local.xml.example` it stopped referencing our development IP. Yay!

Now, this isn't directly related to the question, but because the solution introduced a new bug I want to mention it. Once we renamed the xml file and cleared all of the caches we started seeing a new error.

`PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function setQueryHook() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php on line 347`

In our example file we were defining our database resource inside a single `<default_setup />` node. For our production environment we actually have [a triple-m setup](http://mysql-mmm.org/) with separate IPs for read and write queries so for production instead of a single `<default_setup />` node we had `<default_read />` and `<default_write />` nodes. I have never been able to find documentation on exactly what is allowed and required in resources, but the read / write split was setup per [the instructions in another StackOverflow post on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8972193/488663) and, up until today, worked great.

On a hunch, I renamed the `<default_write />` node to `<default_setup />` and everything magically began working again. I'm not yet sure if the reads and write are correctly splitting, but I'll update this answer once I confirm everything is working.

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure out what was wrong with your `<default_write>` node?

Comment: Sadly, no, I never had the chance to come back around to that and I have since moved on from that project.