# How to have multiple RDS read replicas in Magento?

Tags: mysql, magento, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I need to have multiple read connections to distribute load in my Magento application.
So I did some research and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18785239/1637965)

> it is not possible to use multiple slaves with Magento

but in the [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0hVymqegs9Y&feature=youtu.be)(13:52) given at AWS re:Invent 2014 it is said that Magento supports read replicas.
I tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8972193/1637965) with multiple `<core_read>` tags and multiple `<connection>` tags within a single `<core_read>` tag but it doesn't seem to work. Any idea how this can be achived?

Comment: Maybe it’s not possible to use **multiple** slaves as you quoted, but that wouldn’t rule out a single instance being used as a read connection.

Comment: Have you tried using a round robin CNAMES on Route 53 with endpoints of reading replicas?

Comment: @TomirSchmiteJr., yes that is what I ended up with.

Comment: @WasaeShoaib i'm also trying to enable read replicas on magento 2 community edition, whats the approach you took?